# Show that $g\cdot a:=ag^{-1}$ defines an action of $G$ on itself

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a group. Show that $g\cdot a:=ag^{-1}$ for $g,a\in G$ defines an action of $G$ on itself.

Would I be correct in saying that this definition defines an action on $G$ if $g=e$ where $e$ is the identity in $G$? Because then I think I can say that arbitrarily $e\cdot a=a\cdot e$. And the inverse of $e$ is $e$ so $g=g^{-1}$. Not sure if this is correct or not, if not can someone point me in the right direction? Also, I know that $gag^{-1}=a$ but I don't think that implies $ga=ag^{-1}$, right?

Comment: You seem to be mistaking the operation of the proposed group action with the operation of multiplication in $G$.  They aren't the same (with few exceptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that $g\star a:=ag^{-1}$ defines a (left-)action of $G$ on $G$ you have to show two things

1. $e\star a=a$ for all $a\in G$
2. $g\star(h\star a)=(gh)\star a$ for all $a\in G$ and for all $g,h\in G$

It seems you have confused the inner operation of $G$ (which is denoted by juxtaposition, i.e. writing the product of $g$ and $h$ as $gh$) with the action (which is denoted by $\cdot$ in your question, while I changed it to $\star$ for emphasis).

For example, to show 1. just use the definition
$$e\star a=ae^{-1}=ae=a$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough just to check it for $e$, as in @mrtaurho's answer.  You need to check that the definition of a group action is indeed satisfied.

Also, $gag^{-1}=a\not\implies ga=ag^{-1}$.  And why do you think $gag^{-1}=a$?

Comment: I've never claimed to have given a complete proof; in fact, it was intentionally left incomplete (hopefully my answer does not depict the opposite!).